# Getting mysterious build error after upgrading solution to Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

I have used windows store apps 8.0 in my project and upgraded it to be 8.1. And also upgraded Visual Studio from 2012 to 2013.

First, I got an error that cannot use the Microsoft.VCLibs Version 11.0 and 12.0. So I removed the 11.0 version.

And then I got this errors:

[image]

I tried to find some information on the internet, but nothing.
Also when I double clicked on the error it doesn't bring me to the error's spot.

I have tried to do many things, and nothing helped, so I decided to write this post.

Can someone help me resolve this errors?

**EDIT:**

I am adding some more information, maybe this can lead to the problem:

[image]

**Solved:**

With the help of Hans Passant the errors have fixed. The problem was that I had this duplicate on my resource file:

[image]

I did it twice because one is for buttons (that has content), and one is for message dialogs on code behind.

In Visual Studio 2012 this code was working fine, but somehow, not in Visual Studio 2013.

I deleted the row of Cancel.Content and the errors disappeared and it works fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is somebody else](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fc4f45a8-890a-4df0-b4be-ea2e70bb4dc9/migrate-from-win8-to-81-two-error-when-build-help-to-check?forum=w81prevwCsharp) with the same problem.

I'll just copy Caplan's guidance.  Look through the .resw file(s) in your project and look for a duplicated "Cancel" resource.  I should note that intentionally forcing a duplicate resource produced another message when I built the program on VS2013:

> 1>MakePri : error 0x80073b0f: Processing Resources with error: Duplicate Entry.
>   1>MakePRI : error 0xdef00532: Conflicting values for resource 'Resources/String1'

Same message from either duplicating the resource in the same .resw file and by making a copy of the .resw file and adding it to the project.  So Caplan's explanation isn't exactly a slam-dunk.  I'd pay attention to other projects in your solution that might also have a resource named "Cancel".  A likely scenario when your solution has a dependency on VCLibs, that sounds like you are mixing C# and C++/CX.

Comment: I've edited my post, I've added an image, maybe this can help... And about your answer, it seems to be the right way, but I didn't understand what should I do?

Comment: It doesn't help.  You'll actually have to look *inside* of the .resw file.  Use Notepad.

Comment: Ok, I have opened the .resw files with Notepad, but what should I do with that?

Comment: Find "Cancel".  Look at other .resw files used by projects in solution, look for "Cancel" there as well.  You do sound a bit in over your head, I'd recommend you call Microsoft Support to get help for this.  You can send them your solution and projects and they'll tell you what is wrong with it.

Comment: No need to call :) It's working !!! All I should do was to delete one row of Cancel text it .resw file - I don't know why, but in previous visual studio it was fine. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Whooptidoo, congratulations.

Comment: This doesn't work. The problem is happening in UWP 16299. I don't even have any resource files in my project.

Answer (score 2):

A similar error can also occur if you update a Nuget package in one project, but not in another dependent project also using the same Nuget package.

i.e. it can be a version mismatch error when referencing different versions of a dependency across two dependent projects.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this [MSDN URL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df3bee5f-8081-4425-aca7-70bfbc15fb30/duplicate-items-are-not-supported-by-the-resources-parameter-error-when-building-project?forum=msbuild) which seemed to be pretty helpful.

2 snippets in particular you could try:

> 1. You could actually have a duplicate resource entry in your project file.
> 2. Your obj files could have become corrupt, you need to clear out your obj files (although I haven't seen this problem for a while in my
>      team - it might be fixed in 2008).
> 3. If you are using a custom culture, perhaps with the .Net RegisterCulture method, ensure that the culture has been registered on
>      your computer.  If you've reinstalled your OS and installed VS2008 and
>      you can't build due to this problem it could be because you need to
>      register your custom cultures before you build.  This error seems to
>      be thrown when msbuild cannot find the culture.

Alternatively:

[image]

PS - There is also a Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 available that could possibly help?

[Visual Studio 2012 Update 3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835600)

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's not it, the error message doesn't match.  Are you upvoting your own posts with a sock puppet account?  Tsk, tsk.

Comment: @HansPassant From the re-searching I have done on the net regarding this error, this is what I have found. And to answer your question, No, I do not have a "Sock Puppet Account" - you are more than welcome to interrogate my account if you dont believe me?

Comment: @HansPassant PS - this has now been upvoted by 2 people (I wish I had the rep to tell you who, but I dont) surely if 2 people appreciate this answer then that should be proof enough?

Comment: @HansPassant PS 2 - I still think that this is a resources issue and that the 2nd / alternative option offered in my answer should hopefully help. (i.e. removing the res file etc.)
I can see why you would think what you did, however, I do think the entire answer should help (so do 2 other people) and hence, am offended by the accusation. Should you wish to open a private chat, please feel free to so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have tried re-installing VS 2013, I was getting the same error but it was resolved when I re-installed.

Comment: This looks like a C# app.  Why do you need the VCLibs dependency?  Are you using a C++ component?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after retargeting a working Win8 App for Win81 App, was UI string. Imho it is correct but soehow the VS2013 has some problems with it.

```
Locations       SomeString  
Locations.Text  SomeStringForUI
```

Removing the one of them solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i got a similar build exception on my UWP Project

MakePri : error 0x80073b0f: Processing Resources failed with error: Doppelter Eintrag.
MakePRI : error 0xdef00532: Conflicting values for resource 'System.Design/ClassComments1'

I found a lot of information about the error but no solution. It looks like the error must be in the entry application project but it isn't.
In my case the VS integrated automaticly a reference to System.Activities because a made a mistake.

After i deleted the wrong reference, it works fine again.

Answer (score -1):

Got this error in a UWP Xamarin.Forms project when a fellow developer referenced System.Web in a PCL that the Xamarin.Forms PCL references.

For more info:
[Add System.Web Reference To A Windows 10 Universal App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500227/add-system-web-reference-to-a-windows-10-universal-app)

Comment: Me too but how did you fix it?