# Windows 8.1 Duplicate resources in WindowsBase and PresentationCore

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

When compiling a Windows 8.1 app on Windows 10, it gives following errors:
2>MakePri : error 0x80073b0f: Processing Resources with error: Duplicate Entry.
2>MakePRI : error 0xdef00532: Conflicting values for resource 'ExceptionStringTable/SeekNegative'

Based on answers to this:
[Getting mysterious build error after upgrading solution to Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450277/getting-mysterious-build-error-after-upgrading-solution-to-windows-8-1)

Tried to find duplicate resources. The duplicates are not in my code. But they are generated from Microsoft assemblies.
..\obj\Debug\PresentationCore\en-US\ExceptionStringTable.resw(318):  
..\obj\Debug\PresentationFramework\en-US\ExceptionStringTable.resw(520):  
…\obj\Debug\WindowsBase\en-US\ExceptionStringTable.resw(225):

There are several duplicates in different assemblies like above.

Also this project has MVVMCross dependency.

How do I get rid of this error?