# PRI175: 0x80073b0f - Processing Resources failed with error: Duplicate Entry

Tags: c#, xamarin, compiler-errors, resources

I have a Xamarin Forms application which supports different languages.
Therefore I have multiple
`AppResource.[languagecode].resx` files.

Wanting to add Papiamento as a language I added AppResource.pap.resx

After doing this I get the error

> PRI175: 0x80073b0f - Processing Resources failed with error: Duplicate
> Entry.

This might be caused by the fact that the language code 'pap' is not an official one.

I also would like to add Papiamentu (different language to Papiamento) which also does not have its own 'official' language code.

To me this seems like a bug in MakePri.exe.

The best workaround I found so far is to use a different language code of another not-yet used 'offical lanugage code'.

It seems that other language codes suggested to me by the Visual Studio Addin 'ResX Resource Manager' also have the same problem:

- aa - Afar
- ksf - Bafia
- and multiple others

Answer (score 0):

From the error it sounds like CallHistory or CallHistory.Text is duplicated. Go through your resw files to see if either of these shows up in multiple places.

If you need somebody to take a look at your resource files for you please post a minimal project reproducing the error to your SkyDrive.

Can you check  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/39120/pri-errors-when-compiling-uwp-app.html [Getting mysterious build error after upgrading solution to Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450277/getting-mysterious-build-error-after-upgrading-solution-to-windows-8-1)

Comment: I don't think there is a duplicate key inside my resource file. If I copy AppResource.nl.resx to AppResource.pap.resx I get the error, If I copy it to AppResource.ar.resx I do not get the error.

Comment: It seems that `Papiamento` is not supported , try to select another language .